# Bigdecimal and SQL Server Numeric issue

Tags: sql-server, java

I have a java app, which stores a bigdecimal in a `numeric(11,6)` column. However when I try to store for example `20.89`, it is storing as `20` in the database. All the decimal values are truncated.

Java POJO

```java
public class Store {
    private BigDecimal storeamt;
    ...
    ...
}

DAO {
    private int insertStores(
        List<Store> stores,
        SqlSession session) {

        ....its an ibatis mapper, which will insert the object

        int result = mapper.insertStores(stores, user);
    }
}
```

All the values are inserted fine, except for bigdecimal which is truncating all decimal values. Bigdecimal is mapped to `numeric(11,6)`.

Comment: OK. Getting there. Add the database definition so that's clear. Then, capture the actual query call to see how the code is being resolved. Best method is Extended Events, but you may be able to pull it from cache in this case using sys.dm_exec_query_stats.

Comment: Hi Greeshma. You are using a technology that you do not mention. Typically people using Java use JDBC and I do not see you using that. Please be more specific about the library/extension you use, and document that in your question. Also add a tag for that library/extension ([edit] your question to do so).